set current post category as posts widget query in elementor pro
i want to set current post category as posts widget query in elementor pro
i copy this hook to fanction.php buut it show only current post.
// Showing related posts by current post category in Posts Widget
add_action( 'elementor_pro/posts/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    // Get current post category
    $current_post_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $current_cat = get_the_category( $current_post_id );

    if( empty( $current_cat ) ) {
        return;
    } 

    // Modify the query
    $query->set( 'category__in', [ $current_cat[0]->term_id ] );

    // Make sure we don't get current post
    $not_in = $query->get( 'post__not_in' );
    $not_in[] = $current_post_id;

    // Modify the query
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $not_in );
} );

every one can help me.
thanks
i want to set current post category as posts widget query in elementor pro
